# CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess are not closed when ChromiumWebBrowser is Disposed

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

I am using CefSharp 55 in WPF. every time I make a new `ChromiumWebBrowser`, a new CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe appear in the task manager, which is normal. But they don't disappear when I call `Dispose()` on a `ChromiumWebBrowser`. They only disappear when I close the Apllication, propably because at that time I call `Cef.Shutdown()`. I tried to Force GC after the dispose but i change nothing.

So if the user keep opening and closing tabs in the web browser, we end up with a lot of CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess running which will never be closed exept when the app is closed.

In the constructor of the class extending `ChromiumWebBrowser`,I do

```
var requestContextSettings = new RequestContextSettings
{
    PersistSessionCookies = false,
    IgnoreCertificateErrors = true
};

RequestContext = new RequestContext(requestContextSettings);
```

When I dispose the browser, do

```
browser.Dispose();
browser.RequestContext.Dispose()
```

Did I forgot something?

**Edit**

Apparently it the problem is not limited to CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess. When I  dispose a browser playing a youtube video, The sound of the video is still running. It was working before, the video sound was cut after the dispose. Maybe it is a bug in the new version of CefSharp that I updated recently.

Comment: You don't have to worry about it. read [this](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/GeneralUsage#markdown-header-processes)

Comment: I read the **Process** section. It explain that multiple process will be spawed but it doesn't say if it is normal that they stay alive until the appplication close.

I did a test were I keep openeing and closing web browser tab. I quickly get a out of memory crash. 

Our application is supposed to be running all day without being restarted. It won't last to the end of the day.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found what was the problem. I made an implementation of `ILifeSpanHandler` where I was returning true in `DoClose(...)` because I though returning true mean you tell the browser it can close. But in the doc it say to return false to destroy the browser immediatly.

(https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CefSharp/Handler/ILifeSpanHandler.cs)

After doing this, The CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess are closed when I close the corresponding web browser.

Comment: `return false` is right.
`Cef.Shutdown()`  can close `BrowserSubprocess`, but my main thread still doesn't quit? Did I forgot something?

Comment: @salamander I have the same issue, did you found anything on this?