# Cefsharp hangs form in c#

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I developing windows form application using cefsharp.
I faced issue is cefsharp hangs form which is called another form. Sometimes it's working fine. But sometimes my main form and sub form are hanging and gone not responding.

Here is my main form code that calling Form2:

```
using (Form2 frm = new Form2("Thread " + state.ThreadIndex.ToString() + "\t"))
{
    frm.ShowDialog();
    logging.Info("Thread " + state.ThreadIndex.ToString() + " is finished");
}
```

In Form2, i just dispose ChromiumWebBrowser.
Here is my code:

```
DoClose(browser, browser.GetBrowser());    
browser.Dispose();    
if (this.InvokeRequired)
{
   this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
   {
        this.Close();
   });    
}
else this.Close();
```

Also, I implemented IlifeSpanHandler in [CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess are not closed when ChromiumWebBrowser is Disposed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45919551/cefsharp-browsersubprocess-are-not-closed-when-chromiumwebbrowser-is-disposed).

```
public bool DoClose(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser)
{
     return true;
}
```

Please help me?

Comment: You should be returning false to allow close which is the default. You should not call DoClose yourself, it's called by the framework.

Comment: You can use https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample as a reference.